# css - align div on anther div which have content (::after)

Tags: html, css

I want to align the div on another div. and second div have icon content. my problem is I could not align those divs, one div has an icon the other one is empty.

```css
.outer {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.inner:before {
  content: '\34ds';
  left: -6px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="outer"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: align how? there is no code for align (flex,float,inline-block...). And content lacks and N.

Answer (score 0):

Using Flexbox and align-items property:

```
 <div class="container">
   <div class="outer"></div>
   <div class="inner"></div>
 </div>
```

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

More info about flexbox : https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/#flex-grow